# Profiler shows OpenCL not uses all registers available

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Here is the copy of occupancy analysis of my kernel from the NVIDIA Compute Visual Profiler:

```
Kernel details : Grid size: 300 x 1, Block size: 224 x 1 x 1
Register Ratio      = 0.75  ( 24576 / 32768 ) [48 registers per thread] 
Shared Memory Ratio = 0 ( 0 / 49152 ) [0 bytes per Block] 
Active Blocks per SM    = 2 : 8
Active threads per SM   = 448 : 1536
Occupancy       = 0.291667  ( 14 / 48 )
Achieved occupancy  = 0.291667  (on 14 SMs)
Occupancy limiting factor   = Registers 
Warning: Grid Size (300) is not a multiple of available SMs (14).
```

I am new to openCL and I did a lot of optimisations to bring down the number of registers used so that 3 concurrent blocks can be launched on a SM. However, the profiler only shows that only 2 blocks can run concurrently and the limit factor is registers. But the problem is that it is obvious that my kernel only uses 224 x 48 = 10752 registers per block and therefore, would be capable of running 3 blocks (i.e. 224 x48 x 3 = 32256 registers / 32768 available registers). The problem still exists when I reduce the number of threads per block to 208 which means it should only uses 208 x 48 x 3 = 29952 / 32768 for 3 blocks...

At first, I think it is because of local memory, but my calculation of local memory shows it should be able to launch 3 blocks / SM. And I dont know why the profiler does not show Shared Memory Ratio although my kernel uses local memory.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you computing with your kernel? there are a lot of reasons why the ALU hardware is not fully saturated with work.

Comment: Blocks are always scheduled in multiples of 32. When you go from 224 threads to 208 threads, you have not changed the number of warps per block, and nor the number of registers required per block. Also be aware that the register file has a rather big page size, which is probably why the 224 case doesn't run with 3 blocks per MP

Comment: thanks talonmies, can you please explain a little bit more about register file and page size ? and how does it affect the number of registers available ?